# Why is my server still restarting?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a dedicated server on the SoYouStart (OVH) infrastructure. Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS installed. My server restarts every few minutes and I don't know why. Data center technicians checked the hardware and it looks good. I also did booting with rescue OS, but the tests showed no errors or warnings. It is suspected that many restart processes are still running:

```
root     pts/0        Thu Dec  5 09:18   still logged in    <my ip>
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 09:17   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 08:59   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 08:57   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 08:43   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 08:19   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 08:13   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:53   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:52   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:47   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:41   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:40   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:36   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:32   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:17   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:14   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:12   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 07:07   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 06:45   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 06:38   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 06:33   still running      4.15.0-72-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 06:13   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 06:00   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 05:58   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 05:30   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 05:28   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 05:21   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 05:17   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 05:11   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 04:38   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 04:03   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 03:56   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 03:53   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 03:32   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 03:31   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 03:12   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 03:10   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 02:14   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 02:13   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 02:11   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 02:01   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 01:56   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 01:54   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 01:46   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 01:36   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 01:33   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 01:24   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 01:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 01:15   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 01:05   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 00:59   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 00:57   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 00:36   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 00:31   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 00:25   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Thu Dec  5 00:06   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 23:57   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 23:47   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 23:42   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 23:17   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 23:16   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 23:13   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 23:05   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 22:59   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 22:33   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 22:26   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 22:09   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 22:03   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 22:00   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 20:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 20:22   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 20:08   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 20:05   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 19:24   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 19:04   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 18:56   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 18:09   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 17:59   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 17:37   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
root     pts/0        Wed Dec  4 17:34 - crash  (00:02)     <my ip>
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 17:24   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 17:18   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 16:56   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 16:38   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 16:15   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 16:00   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 14:24   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 13:45   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 13:19   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 12:56   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 12:34   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 12:10   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 12:00   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 11:46   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 11:37   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 11:27   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 11:19   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 11:17   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 11:12   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 11:06   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:54   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:51   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:49   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:45   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:44   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:39   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:35   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:31   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:24   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:22   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 10:12   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:59   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:53   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:47   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:35   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:33   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:27   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:21   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:19   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:14   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 09:08   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 08:59   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 08:55   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 08:54   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 08:53   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 08:35   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 08:33   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 08:31   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 08:27   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 08:07   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 07:58   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 07:52   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 07:41   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 07:12   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 06:38   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 06:34   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 06:24   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 06:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 06:10   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 05:51   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 05:39   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 05:35   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 05:29   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 05:21   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 04:28   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 04:21   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 04:14   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 04:08   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 04:04   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 03:21   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 03:14   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 03:13   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 02:56   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 02:43   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 02:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 02:13   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 01:44   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 01:30   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 01:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 00:47   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 00:42   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 00:34   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 00:26   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 00:15   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Wed Dec  4 00:09   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:59   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:50   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:44   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:42   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:40   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:34   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:28   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:20   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:13   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:08   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:05   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 23:00   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 22:36   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 22:22   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 22:15   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 22:14   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 21:44   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 21:25   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 21:15   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 21:05   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 20:25   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 19:55   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 19:35   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 19:30   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 19:10   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 18:48   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 18:40   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 18:30   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 17:54   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 17:49   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 17:48   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 17:42   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 17:33   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 17:28   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 17:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 16:35   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 15:54   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 15:49   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 12:34   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 12:25   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 12:08   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 12:03   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 11:07   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 11:02   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 10:24   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 10:20   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 10:13   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 10:10   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 09:56   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 09:50   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 09:41   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 09:39   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 09:34   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 09:30   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 09:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 09:05   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 09:04   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 08:39   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 07:20   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 07:14   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 06:50   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 06:45   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 06:33   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 05:59   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 05:34   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 05:27   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 05:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 05:08   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 04:55   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 04:35   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 04:15   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 03:37   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 02:52   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 02:33   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 02:26   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 00:55   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 00:38   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 00:32   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 00:26   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 00:20   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Tue Dec  3 00:11   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 23:47   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 23:43   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 23:12   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 23:07   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 22:45   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 22:44   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 22:42   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 22:17   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 21:40   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 21:39   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 21:24   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 21:18   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 20:39   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 20:25   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 20:21   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 20:06   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 19:50   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 19:48   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 19:23   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 19:19   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 19:12   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 19:03   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 18:57   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 18:32   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 18:28   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 18:21   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 17:54   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 17:19   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 16:57   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 15:57   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 15:27   still running      4.15.0-70-generic
root     pts/0        Mon Dec  2 15:26 - down   (00:00)     <my ip>
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 15:26 - 15:27  (00:01)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 15:24 - 15:27  (00:02)     4.15.0-70-generic
root     pts/0        Mon Dec  2 14:37 - crash  (00:47)     <my ip>
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 14:36 - 15:27  (00:50)     4.15.0-70-generic
root     pts/0        Mon Dec  2 14:26 - down   (00:09)     <my ip>
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 14:17 - 14:36  (00:19)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 14:07 - 14:36  (00:28)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 14:00 - 14:36  (00:36)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 13:01 - 14:36  (01:35)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 12:57 - 14:36  (01:38)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 12:31 - 14:36  (02:04)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 12:20 - 14:36  (02:15)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 11:48 - 14:36  (02:47)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 11:37 - 14:36  (02:58)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 11:24 - 14:36  (03:11)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 11:21 - 14:36  (03:15)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 11:10 - 14:36  (03:26)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 10:08 - 14:36  (04:27)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 10:06 - 14:36  (04:29)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 09:56 - 14:36  (04:39)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 09:48 - 14:36  (04:47)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 09:19 - 14:36  (05:17)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 08:57 - 14:36  (05:38)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 08:20 - 14:36  (06:15)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 08:15 - 14:36  (06:20)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 08:14 - 14:36  (06:21)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 08:02 - 14:36  (06:33)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 07:43 - 14:36  (06:52)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 07:35 - 14:36  (07:00)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 07:33 - 14:36  (07:03)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 07:27 - 14:36  (07:08)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 06:59 - 14:36  (07:37)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 06:37 - 14:36  (07:59)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 06:32 - 14:36  (08:03)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 06:24 - 14:36  (08:11)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 06:18 - 14:36  (08:17)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 05:58 - 14:36  (08:37)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 05:52 - 14:36  (08:43)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 05:47 - 14:36  (08:48)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 05:35 - 14:36  (09:01)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 05:21 - 14:36  (09:15)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 05:17 - 14:36  (09:19)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 05:14 - 14:36  (09:22)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 05:06 - 14:36  (09:29)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 04:58 - 14:36  (09:37)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 04:47 - 14:36  (09:48)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 04:23 - 14:36  (10:13)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 04:14 - 14:36  (10:21)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 04:08 - 14:36  (10:27)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 04:06 - 14:36  (10:30)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 03:31 - 14:36  (11:04)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 03:19 - 14:36  (11:16)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 02:49 - 14:36  (11:46)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 02:44 - 14:36  (11:52)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 02:40 - 14:36  (11:56)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 02:32 - 14:36  (12:03)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 02:29 - 14:36  (12:07)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 02:23 - 14:36  (12:12)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 02:04 - 14:36  (12:32)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 01:27 - 14:36  (13:09)     4.15.0-70-generic
reboot   system boot  Mon Dec  2 01:22 - 14:36  (13:14)     4.15.0-70-generic
```

Comment: it's the same with an OVH VPS, with Arch Linux. As soon as I don't connect in a couple of days, the server stops operating and I have to restart it manually so I can use it.